# Deployment to GAE failing after project has been restored

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, restore

I had a project deployment to GAE using cloud build which was working fine, But I deleted the project by mistake.  But after the restore, the deployment is failing with

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.

I see this in the cloud build logs: even when the Cloud build service account has the App Engine Admin Permissions

WARNING: Unable to verify that the Appengine Flexible API is enabled for project []. You may not have permission to list enabled services on this project. If it is not enabled, this may cause problems in running your deployment. Please ask the project owner to ensure that the Appengine Flexible API has been enabled and that this account has permission to list enabled APIs.

Also, the permissions for the account owner has changed from : 1350/1578 to  1266/1578. How can I fix that?

Comment: Could you confirm that the **Google App Engine Flexible Environment** API enabled? You can check it by searching for ‘Google App Engine Flexible Environment’ on the [**API Library page**](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/apis/library?_ga=2.225057630.-593335694.1571214295) in the Cloud Console. (*If you don’t see it on the list enable it through the ‘**ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES**’ button.*)

Comment: After the project was restored, all API that were earlier enabled were disabled and I did enable the API.

Comment: Have you enabled the Cloud Build's Service account [**permissions**](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/settings?_ga=2.213130960.-593335694.1571214295)(see the link) for Google App Engine?

Comment: Cloud build service accound does have app engine admin permissions. The deployment is failing not only from the cloud build but also when I try gcloud app deploy from my local machine (owner permissions). The same app is working fine in a different environment. Is there any changes that happen to the google app engine when a project is deleted and then restored ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate the issue you're experiencing by creating a new project and deploying a simple HelloWorld [app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) in **GAE Flexible** environment.

I have deleted my project and then restored it, and, after that, I was unable to deploy the app again. The issue was solved once I made sure my **Google App Engine Flexible Environment** API is enabled and linked my **[Billing Account](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing)** again *(as it gets removed when you delete the project)*.

---

## EDIT:

After further research, I found this [**page**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73583699#comment39) in the GCP [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Based on the information from that page, the error you are experiencing can occur for various reasons. It can be related to [**quotas**](https://console.cloud.google.com/quotas) *(e.g. CPU cores, memory, public IP addresses)* or, sometimes, the **region** where you are trying to deploy.

As it was confirmed by the engineer, trying to **re-deploy**, or to deploy in a **different region** often resolves the issue. However, if the issue persists and you have a [support package](https://cloud.google.com/support/), I'd recommend you to contact GCP support as the issue is too broad to troubleshoot it here and may require a project inspection.

Comment: Billing account is enabled.  Instance is getting created, but the application is not right. and fails with  ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.

Comment: @user1089109, thanks for the update! I've edited my answer adding more information.